# Running conda environments in Google Colab

Tags: python, conda, google-colaboratory

Is it possible to run conda environments in google colab? I successfully installed conda and created an environment. But I get an error when trying to run the environment.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To run conda environments within google colab, you can use a %%bash magic line. Then you would have to run python again and execute your python commands. See below for example.

Example:

```
# activate your conda environment
%%bash
source activate myenv
python

# python commands are ready to run within your environment
import sys
print("Python version")
print (sys.version)
```

- 1st line opens a "semi-permanent" bash shell
- 2nd line activates your local environment
- 3rd line goes back to a python executable
- 4th line onwards are normal python commands

Comment: source active myenv for some reason doesn't activate the environment

Comment: Does semi-permanent mean it only exists during execution of the current cell?

Comment: Yes, this only works in a single cell, not across multiple cells.